# Dev c++ Error, No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I am creating a program, and when I run it, instead of the program I get an error that says, No such file or directory. May you please help me on this? Thank you. The full error is:

> C:\Users\Home\Documents\Cpp\g++.exe   [Error] C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libopengl32.a: No such file or directory

this is my code,

```
    #include <iostream> // including required headers
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//several functions for certain operations
void menu();
void game();
void controls(char s[][22],int temp[][22],int eating);
void credits();
void table(char s[][22],int score);
bool checkFood(char s[][22],int fx,int fy);
void spawnFood(char s[][22],int & fx,int & fy);
bool gameover(char s[][22],int temp[][22]);
void endgame(int score,int highscore);
void help();
void options();
void difficulty();
void pause();

int lenght; //several variable
char contr = 'n';
int chek[32][22];
double diff=0.5; //difficulty variable, how fast snake moves (default-normal(0.5 sec)

int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); //seeding random numb gen
    int i;
    char sl; //selection variable
    for(i=0;i<9999;i++)
    {
        if(i>0)
        {
            cout<<""<<endl;
            cout<<"Do you want to play again ? [y/n]   ";
            cin>>sl;
            if(sl=='y')
            {
                system("cls"); //clearing screen
                goto start;
            }
            else goto quit;
        }
        start: //starting program
        {
            menu(); //showing menu screen
        }
        cin>>sl; //selections for playing,options and exit
        if(sl=='1')
        {
            system("cls"); //clears screen
            game(); //calling game function, starting game
            i=1;
        }
        else if(sl=='2')
        {
            options();
            system("cls");
            goto start;
            i=1;
        }
        else if(sl=='3') goto quit;
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            i=1;
            goto start;
        }
    }
    quit: //quits program
        {
            system("exit");
        }

    return 0;
}


void table(char s[][22],int score)  //function for showing table (screen in which snake moves
{
    int x=32; //i am using coordinates for displaying the table
    int y=22;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            if(j<(x-1)) cout<<s[j][i];
            if(j==(x-1)) cout<<s[j][i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Your score: "<<score;
}

void game()
{
    char s[32][22]; //a 2-dimensional array for storing all particles in the screen;
    int temp[32][22]; //an array for numbering snake parts and storing them
    int i,j,fx,fy,x,y,score=0,highscore=score; //several variables
    double k;
    int eating; //if snake eats food, this becomes 1, and snake gains lenght
    //preparations for game: setting table borders
    for(i=0;i<22;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<32;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i==21) s[j][i]='-';
            if(i>0 && i<21) s[j][i]=' ';
            if(j==0 || j==31) s[j][i]='|';
        }
    }
    spawnFood(s,fx,fy); //calling food spawn function
    for(y=1;y<21;y++)
    {
        for(x=1;x<31;x++)
        {
            temp[x][y]=0; //setting all the temp values to 0,
        }                 //to see where snake parts are, and where nothing (0);
    }
    s[17][10]='o'; //finally, sets primary snake position. o is head.
    s[16][10]='*';
    s[15][10]='*';

    temp[15][10]=3; //numbering snake parts
    temp[16][10]=2;
    temp[17][10]=1;

    system("cls");
    table(s,score); //calling table function to show a table
    lenght=3; //snake primary lenght

    while(true) //game starts
    {
        eating=0; //setting value to 0, because snake hasnt eaten anything
        Sleep(diff*1000); //delaying some time, how fast snake moves depends on difficulty
        if(kbhit()) //checking if some key is pressed
        {
            contr=getch(); //if pressed, getting info about that key. this is needed for snake controls
            if(contr=='0') pause(); //if 0, pauses game
            goto movemake; //starts making snake moves
        }
        else
        {
            goto movemake; //if no key is pressed, snake just moves
        }
        movemake:
        {
            for(x=1;x<31;x++) //a loop for checking where are snake parts
            {
                for(y=1;y<21;y++)
                {
                    if(s[x][y]=='*')
                    {
                        chek[x][y]=1; //this is needed for checking if snake hits its tail or borders
                    }
                    else chek[x][y]=0;
                }
            }
            if(checkFood(s,fx,fy)==true) //if snake eats something, some info needs to be sent for snake to gain lenght
            {
                eating=1;
                score=score+1;
                controls(s,temp,eating); //calling snake control and movement function
                spawnFood(s,fx,fy);
            }
            else
            {
                controls(s,temp,eating); //snake only moves
            }

            if(gameover(s,temp)==true) goto gameEnd; //if snake has hit something, game terminates
            else
            {
                goto LoopEnd;
            }
        }

        LoopEnd: //when loop ends, screen clears, updated table and score shows
        {
            system("cls");
            table(s,score);
            if(score>highscore) highscore=score;
        }
    }
    gameEnd:
    {
        endgame(score,highscore); //calls endgame screen
        return; //returns to int main
    }
}


void controls(char s[][22],int temp[][22],int eating) //finally, the coolest part :)
{
    int i,x,y;
    for(i=lenght;i>0;i--) //snake starts moving from tail to head
    {
        if(i==lenght) //when i equals to the number of snakes last part
        {
            for(x=1;x<31;x++)
            {
                for(y=1;y<21;y++)
                {
                    if(temp[x][y]==i && s[x][y]=='*')
                    {
                        if(eating==0) //if snake doesnt eat anything, the last part just disappears
                        {
                            s[x][y]=' '; temp[x][y]=0;
                            x=30;
                            y=20;
                        }
                        else if(eating==1) //if snake eats food, it moves, but the last part stays there,
                        {                  //giving snake 1 more part
                            s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=lenght+1;
                            lenght++; //this new part number will be new length
                            x=30;
                            y=20;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(i>1 && i<lenght) // all other snake parts stays where they are, but
        {                        // their values (temp) will increase by 1
            for(x=1;x<31;x++)
            {
                for(y=1;y<21;y++)
                {
                    if(temp[x][y]==i && s[x][y]=='*')
                    {
                        temp[x][y]=i+1;
                        x=30;
                        y=20;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(i==1) //the hardest part, when i is equal to snake's head value.
        {
            for(x=1;x<31;x++)
            {
                for(y=1;y<21;y++)
                {
                    if(temp[x][y]==i && s[x][y]=='o')
                    {
                        movecheck:
                        if(contr!='1' && contr!='2' && contr!='3' && contr!='4') //if no control button is pressed,
                        {                                                       //snake just moves in its direction forward
                        s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=i+1;
                        if(temp[x-1][y]==i+2) //several situations
                        {
                            s[x+1][y]='o'; temp[x+1][y]=1;
                            return; //when snake moves its head, loop ends, we return to void game
                        }
                        else if(temp[x+1][y]==i+2)
                        {
                            s[x-1][y]='o'; temp[x-1][y]=1;
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(temp[x][y+1]==i+2)
                        {
                            s[x][y-1]='o'; temp[x][y-1]=1;
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(temp[x][y-1]==i+2)
                        {
                            s[x][y+1]='o'; temp[x][y+1]=1;
                            return;
                        }
                        }
                        else if(contr=='1') //if control buttons are pressed, snake moves to that direction
                        {
                            if(temp[x][y-1]==0) //if the value of the square in front of snake's head equals 0
                            {                   //snake can move to it
                            s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=i+1;
                            s[x][y-1]='o'; temp[x][y-1]=1;
                            return;
                            }
                            else //if not, we return to checking if control button is pressed
                            {    //the new contr value will not be control button
                                contr='n';
                                goto movecheck;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(contr=='2')
                        {
                            if(temp[x][y+1]==0)
                            {
                            s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=i+1;
                            s[x][y+1]='o'; temp[x][y+1]=1;
                            return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                contr='n';
                                goto movecheck;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(contr=='3')
                        {
                            if(temp[x-1][y]==0)
                            {
                            s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=i+1;
                            s[x-1][y]='o'; temp[x-1][y]=1;
                            return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                contr='n';
                                goto movecheck;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(contr=='4')
                        {
                            if(temp[x+1][y]==0)
                            {
                            s[x][y]='*'; temp[x][y]=i+1;
                            s[x+1][y]='o'; temp[x+1][y]=1;
                            return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                contr='n';
                                goto movecheck;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} //finally, the snake moves :)

bool checkFood(char s[][22],int fx,int fy) //function for checking if snake has eaten the food
{
    int x,y,c=0;
    for(x=1;x<31;x++)
    {
        for(y=1;y<21;y++)
        {
            if(s[x][y]=='o' && x==fx && y==fy)
            {
                c=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(c==1) return true;
    else return false;
}

void spawnFood(char s[][22],int & fx,int & fy) //function for spawning new food
{
    //food spawning
        int i,j;
        fx=(rand()%30)+1; //generates random value
        fy=(rand()%20)+1;
        for(j=1;j<31;j++)
        {
            for(i=1;i<21;i++)
            {
                if(s[j][i]!='*' && s[j][i]!='o') //checks if there is something in generated value square
                {
                    s[fx][fy]='+';
                    return;
                }
                else //if there is something, generates again, and checks
                {
                    fx=(rand()%30)+1;
                    fy=(rand()%20)+1;
                    i=1;
                    j=1;
                }
            }
        }
}

bool gameover(char s[][22],int temp[][22]) //checking if snake has hit its tail or borders,
{
    int x,y,c=0;

    for(x=0;x<32;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<22;y++)
        {
            if((x==0 || x==31 || y==0 || y==21) && s[x][y]=='o')
            {
                c=1;
            }
            if(chek[x][y]==1 && s[x][y]=='o')
            {
                c=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(c==1) return true; //if yes, game ends
    if(c==0) return false;
}

void endgame(int score,int highscore) //just some screens for certain actions
{
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" ------------------------------------------------------------------------- "<<endl;
    cout<<"|    *****       *      *       *  ******       ****   *       *  *****  ****    |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   *           * *     * *   * *  *           *    *   *     *   *      *   *   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   *  ****    *   *    *  * *  *  *****       *    *    *   *    ****   ****    |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   *  *  *   *******   *   *   *  *           *    *     * *     *      * *     |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|    *****   *       *  *       *  ******       ****       *      *****  *   *   |"<<endl;
    cout<<" ------------------------------------------------------------------------- "<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                        Y O U R   S C O R E : "<<score<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                        H I G H   S C O R E : "<<highscore<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
}

void menu()
{
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<" ------------------------------------------------  "<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                                | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|    ******   *     *      *      *  *  *****    | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|   *         * *   *     * *     * *   *        | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|    ******   *  *  *    *   *    **    ****     | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|          *  *   * *   *******   * *   *        | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|    ******   *     *  *       *  *  *  *****    | "<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                                | "<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------  "<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                     M E N U:    "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                  1: Start Game  "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                  2: Options    "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                  3: Exit     "<<endl<<endl;
}

void help()
{
    char sel;
    system("cls");
    while(true)
    {
    cout<<" ----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                     1 - up                   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|            3 - left        4 - right         |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                    2 - down                  |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                    0 - Pause                 |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|                                              |"<<endl;
    cout<<" ---------------------------------------------- "<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Go back? [y/n]  ";
    cin>>sel;
    if(sel=='y') return;
    else system("cls");
    }
}

void credits()
{
    char sel;
    system("cls");
    while(true)
    {
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"        Idea maker: Zaniac"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"               Lead programmer: Zaniac "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"               Designer: Zaniac "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"               Testers: Zaniac "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"               Special thanks to: Zaniac "<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Go back? [y/n]  ";
    cin>>sel;
    if(sel=='y') return;
    else system("cls");
    }
}

void options()
{
    char sel;
    system("cls");
    while(true)
    {
    system("cls");
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                          O P T I O N S:      "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       1: Choose Difficulty   "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       2: Controls            "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       3: Credits             "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       4: Go Back             "<<endl<<endl;
    cin>>sel;
    if(sel=='1') difficulty();
    else if(sel=='2') help();
    else if(sel=='3') credits();
    else if(sel=='4') return;
    else system("cls");
    }
}

void difficulty() //function for setting difficulty (how fast snake moves
{
    char sel;
    system("cls");
    while(true)
    {
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"          C U R R E N T   D I F F I C U L T Y:"<<endl<<endl;
    if(diff==1) cout<<"                         E A S Y"<<endl<<endl;
    else if(diff==0.5) cout<<"                       N O R M A L"<<endl<<endl;
    else if(diff==0.2) cout<<"                         H A R D"<<endl<<endl;
    else if(diff==0.1) cout<<"                 S U P E R   H A R D"<<endl<<endl;
    else if(diff==0.03) cout<<"                 H O P E L E S S"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"          C H O O S E   D I F F I C U L T Y :"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       1: Easy        "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       2: Normal      "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       3: Hard        "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       4: Super Hard  "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       5: Hopeless  "<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"                       6: Go Back     "<<endl<<endl;
    cin>>sel;
    if(sel=='1')  //there are 5 ready difficulties
    {
        diff=1;
        system("cls");
    }
    else if(sel=='2')
    {
        diff=0.5;
        system("cls");
    }
    else if(sel=='3')
    {
        diff=0.2;
        system("cls");
    }
    else if(sel=='4')
    {
        diff=0.1;
        system("cls");
    }
    else if(sel=='5')
    {
        diff=0.03;
        system("cls");
    }
    else if(sel=='6') return;
    else system("cls");
    }
}

void pause() //pauses game
{
    char c;
    cout<<""<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Game paused. Do you want to continue? [y/n]  ";
    ooo:
    cin>>c;
    if(c=='y') return;
    else goto ooo;
}
```

My make file is this, 
I updated it to what you told me smead.

```
 # Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = Snake.o
LINKOBJ  = Snake.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libopengl32.a"
INCS     = -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
BIN      = snake.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

Snake.o: Snake.cpp
    $(CPP) -c Snake.cpp -o Snake.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the way you try to run it, not with the code.

Comment: I just click compile and run. But there is a project called Makefile.win and the error seems to be coming from that.

Comment: If it is with the way I run it how can I fix it?

Comment: It says on the title, Dev C++

Comment: What do you mean by "run", did the program compile successfully?

Comment: It compiled but after it compiled it gave me the error.

Comment: Go to the directory(folder) where your IDE creates your program executable(.exe) and see if it is successfully created.

Comment: what is the directory folder usually called?

Comment: Depends on you IDE, usually found at the linker options->output directory

Comment: May you tell me where the linker options are please? Sorry I am not that good with programming.

Answer (score 0):

In your makefile in this line:

```
LIBS     = -L"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Users/Home/Documents/Cpp/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libopengl32.a
```

The last file needs to be written like the others:

```
-L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libopengl32.a"
```

Answer (score 0):

there is only an error in `compiler options`. it must be filled correctly! Copy and paste

```
-static-libgcc -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32
```

there. without any extra characters. because I had the same error and fixed it. the error line is not filled correctly. I will be happy to help you :)